# SSL Pinning with AFNetworking doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, afnetworking, pinning

I'm trying to add SSL pinning to my app, with a self-signed certificate, but I can't seem to get it to work.
I have tried everything I could find on the internet with no success, and not being an expert at how SSL works doesn't help.

I'm using objective-c with the latest version of AFNetworking.

I made a very simple piece of code to test my API calls (I'm using a placeholder URL for this post) :

```objectivec
NSString *url = @"https://api.example.net/webservice";

    NSString *cerPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"example.net" ofType:@"der"];
    NSData *certData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:cerPath];

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer new];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer new];

    AFSecurityPolicy *policy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeCertificate];
    [policy setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];
    [policy setValidatesDomainName:NO];
    policy.pinnedCertificates = [NSSet setWithObject:certData];

    manager.securityPolicy = policy;

    [manager POST:url parameters:nil headers:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"SUCCESS");
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        NSLog(@"FAILURE : %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }];
```

Every time I try executing this code, I get a failure with the following error :

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “api.example.net” which could put your confidential information at risk."
```

I tried using different formats for my certificate (.der, .cer, ...), but I still always get the same error.

I tried using `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` in my info.plist but nothing changes.

To make sure I'm using working code, I also downloaded the example project from a [Ray Wenderlich tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1484288-preventing-man-in-the-middle-attacks-in-ios-with-ssl-pinning), but my own certificate is still invalid (in the tutorial they use the stackexchange certificate, this one works).

I have been researching this issue for days and haven't found a solution yet.

The same certificate works perfectly on our Android app, as well as Postman.

Is this because I use a self-signed certificate and iOS doesn't like it?
Is there anything obvious I missed in my code or in my app configuration?
Is there something specific to implement server-side to make sure it works with iOS?
Do I have to export my certificate in a very specific format?

Any information is welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at an old project where I used self signed certificates without a problem. These are just comments that may help - I make them here because I have more space and can format them better.

The `der` version worked.

In `Info.plist` you need something like the following.

```
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>server1.local</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
            <key>server2.local</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
            <key>server3.local</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Note your error message - it is complaining about the *server* certificate, so maybe the problem is in the DNS or server certificate. Both needs to be correct and the name you use e.g. `server1.local` must match the DNS name of the server as well as the `CN` of the certificate for iOS to work.

I added *both* the CA and the server certificates to the chain in iOS.

I trust this will help you.

FWIW my implementation did not use AFNetworking but I used `SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates` inside `URLSession:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler:` in the `NSURLSessionDelegate` that I used to support a normal `NSURLRequest`.

Here is that piece of code.

```
// Look to see if we can handle the challenge
- ( void ) URLSession:( NSURLSession                 * ) session
  didReceiveChallenge:( NSURLAuthenticationChallenge * ) challenge
    completionHandler:( void ( ^ ) ( NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential * ) ) completionHandler
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    NSLog( @"didReceiveChallenge %@ %zd", challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod, ( ssize_t ) challenge.previousFailureCount );
#endif
    NSURLCredential      * credential = nil;
    NSURLProtectionSpace * protectionSpace;
    SecTrustRef            trust;
    int                    err;

    // Setup
    protectionSpace = challenge.protectionSpace;
    trust = protectionSpace.serverTrust;
    credential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:trust];

    if ( protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust )
    {
        // Build up the trust anchor using server certificates
        err = SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates ( trust, ( CFArrayRef ) fhWebSupportDelegate.serverCertificates );
        SecTrustResultType trustResult = 0;

        if ( err == noErr )
        {
            SecTrustSetAnchorCertificatesOnly ( trust, true );
            err = SecTrustEvaluate ( trust, & trustResult );
#ifdef DEBUG
            NSLog ( @"Trust result %lu", ( unsigned long ) trustResult );
#endif
        }

        BOOL trusted =
        ( err == noErr ) &&
        ( ( trustResult == kSecTrustResultProceed ) || ( trustResult == kSecTrustResultUnspecified ) || ( trustResult == kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure ) );


        // Return based on whether we decided to trust or not
        if ( trusted )
        {
#ifdef DEBUG
            NSLog ( @"Trust evaluation succeeded" );
#endif
            if ( completionHandler )
            {
                completionHandler ( NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, credential );
            }
        }
        else
        {
#ifdef DEBUG
            NSLog ( @"Trust evaluation failed" );
#endif
            if ( completionHandler )
            {
                completionHandler ( NSURLSessionAuthChallengeCancelAuthenticationChallenge, credential );
            }
        }
    }
    else if ( completionHandler )
    {
        completionHandler ( NSURLSessionAuthChallengePerformDefaultHandling, nil );
    }
}
```

Here `fhWebSupportDelegate.serverCertificates` returns an array with the CA as well as the server certificate. Also I was extremely lenient in when I granted trust to the server as can be seen in the code.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll look into it and see if I manage to make it work